# C GPIO hex numbering

Tags: c, hex

I have been given the following bit of code as an example:

Make port 0 bits 0-2 outputs, other to be inputs.

```
FIO0DIR = 0x00000007;
```

Set P0.0, P0.1, P0.2 all low (0)

```
FIO0CLR = 0x00000007;
```

I have been told that the port has 31 LED's attached to it. I cant understand why, to enable the first 3 outputs, it is 0x00000007 not 0x00000003?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These GPIO config registers are bitmaps.

Use your Windows calculator to convert the hex to binary:

0x00000007 = 111, or with 32 bits - 00000000000000000000000000000111 // three outputs

0x00000003 = 11,  or with 32 bits - 00000000000000000000000000000011 // only two outputs

Answer (score 2):

Because the value you write to the register is a binary bit-mask, with a bit being one meaning "this is an output". You don't write the "number of outputs I'd like to have", you are setting 8 individual flags at the same time.

The number 7 in binary is `00000111`, so it has the lower-most three bits set to 1, which here seems to mean "this is an output". The decimal value 3, on the other hand, is just `00000011` in binary, thus only having two bits set to 1, which clearly is one too few.

Bits are indexed from the right, starting at 0. The decimal value of bit number *n* is 2<sup>*n*</sup>. The decimal value of a binary number with more than one bit set is simply the sum of all the values of all the set bits.

So, for instance, the decimal value of the number with bits 0, 1 and 2 set is 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> = 1 + 2 + 4 = 7.

Here is an awesome ASCII table showing the 8 bits of a byte and their individual values:

```
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
index | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
value |128| 64| 32| 16| 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```